# Download HTML and Images with WGet without first few lines

Tags: php, html, curl, wget

I'm attempting to use `wget` with the -p option to download specific documents and the images linked in the HTML.

The problem is, the site that is hosting the HTML has some non-html information preceding the HTML.  This is causing `wget` to not interpret the document as HTML and doesn't search for images.

**Is there a way to have `wget` strip the first X lines and/or force searching for images?**

**Example URL:**

- http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/13239/000119312510070346/ds4.htm

**First Lines of Content:**

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>S-4
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>ds4.htm
<DESCRIPTION>FORM S-4
<TEXT>
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Form S-4</TITLE>
```

**Last Lines of Content:**

```
</BODY></HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
```

**EDIT:** Solutions in PHP are certainly accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget is actually detecting the img tags. The issue is the website is question has a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) that disallows /Archives. Wget honors that request and does not retrieve additional documents.

However, you can use the downloaded document as input to wget to retrieve related documents:

**wget -l 1 --base=*url* --force-html -i** ***file***

Comment: Great find!  I didn't even think to look at the robots file.  Well, your alternate method gave me some issues (due to anchor links in the file), so instead I'm just bypassing the Robots file with `-e robots=off`  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could use this function to strip out X lines:

```
function strip_toplines($string,$lines){
    $string = explode(PHP_EOL,$string);
    foreach($string as $line_num => $line){
        if($line_num>($lines - 1)){
            $output .= $line . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return trim($output);
}
```

and then this:

```
strip_toplines(file_get_contents($url),6);
```

Comment: True, but I need to download all the images from the HTML as well.